# How to restrict AWS CLI to only look for credentials in environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm using the `aws` CLI in a CI/CD pipeline, where I want it to fail, if credentials are not available in environment variables. However, it currently doesn't, as `aws sts get-caller-identity` succeeds, because it uses the credentials for the EC2 instance profile.

How can I specify that I valid credential sources as command-line parameters?

Comment: Not sure which CI/CD pipeline you are using, but is there a reason you prefer to supply credentials in environment variables rather than the IAM instance profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to fail, if credentials are not available in environment variables

Assuming you are using bash, you could use:

```bash
if [[ -z "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" || -z "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" ]]; then 
  echo "AWS credentials are not available as environment variables"; 
  exit 1; 
fi
```

this would error if either `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are unset.